# Dual monitors on login are working in a mirrored mode instead of be handled as extension

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, login, lightdm

I have a laptop and recently connected second monitor (VGA). The problem is when I first boot both monitors show same login screen (like in the mirroring mode).

After login in, both monitors are working as expected (the one is an extension of another). If I lock the screen the login screen appears only on one display.

I am using xfce and lightdm.

I guess the problem is with the boot order of some parts of my system. Like lightdm on boot doesn't know about settings of dual-monitor setup and acts by default.

Can anybody help to make lightdm works as expected on the boot?

Comment: Or it is how your hardware works. You say the problem goes away after you login.

Comment: The way it is working is the expected way. Your settings are your user's settings, they come up after you login. PS - It's called "mirrored", not paralel.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, you're right "mirroring", sorry. So nothing I can do with this?

Comment: @David Yes, goes away because I have my user settings I guess.

Comment: My Toshiba laptop does the exact same thing. As far as I am concerned nothing to fix.  But that is just me.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the pointers, I will dig in that direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this line in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
display-setup-script=xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --auto --output DP-1-1 --right-of eDP-1-1 --auto
```

Where `eDP-1-1` is my laptop's display and `DP-1-1` is second monitor. I made it hard-coded, but it can be automated.

The only bad outcome is after logging in there is a second when both monitors show white color.